# regex to get top parent directory without /

Tags: string, groovy, path

Looking for a regex given a path/to/filename.ext I want to determine the topmost parent path.

examples:
'foo/bar/baz/file.ext'
'file2.ext'
'fooz/file3.ext'

should return 'foo' and 'fooz'

Language used is groovy.

Comment: what should it pull from `file2.ext`? no match? empty string?

Comment: Do you need to use a regex, or why don't you use `java.nio.Path`?

Comment: file2.ext should be empty, yes.

Comment: in this particular case I need a regex.  If done in native groovy, how would you?

Comment: What about windows paths which have `\\` as a separator?

Comment: dont care about windows paths in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the proper way to extract components of a pathname is to use tools designed for just that; in the case of Groovy, that would be `java.nio.file.Path` and [@tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74043430/797049).

But the asker requested a regular-expression-based solution, so here is one:

```
pat = ~'^[^/]*(?=/)'
for (str in ['foo/bar/baz/file.ext', 'file2.ext', 'fooz/file3.ext']) {
  print str + ': '
  if (m = str =~ pat) {
    println '"'+m[0]+'"'
  } else {
    println 'NONE'
  }
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
foo/bar/baz/file.ext: "foo"
file2.ext: NONE
fooz/file3.ext: "fooz"
```

The pattern `^[^/]*` matches a (longest-possible) sequence of zero or more (`*`) non-slash characters (`[^/]`) starting at the beginning of the line (`^`).

That would be enough by itself, except for the requirement that a string such as `file2.ext`, with no slashes at all, not match. The lookahead assertion `(?=/)` causes the pattern to match only if the matched text is followed by a slash.

Comment: i don't disagree.  both this and tim_yates should be correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.nio.file.Path

// So given the inputs from the question
def inputs = [
        'foo/bar/baz/file.ext',
        'file2.ext',
        'fooz/file3.ext'
]

def results = inputs.collect {
    // Convert each of them to a Path
    Path.of(it).with {
        // If it has more than 1 element, return the first component
        // else return an empty string (it's just a filename)
        it.nameCount > 1 ? it.subpath(0, 1).toString() : ''
    }
}

// Check results
assert results == ['foo', '', 'fooz']
```